# GAE dont run composer after deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, composer-php, google-app-engine-php

I develop a simple app for GAE on php. 
In local env all is ok, but after "gcloud app deploy" a have an error about autoload.php - No such file or directory.
I use composer only for autoload my classes - not an external dependences.
GAE standard, project without billing

What i do locally:

```
composer install 
dev_appserver.py app.test.yaml
```

and aplication is working perfect.

But after deploy:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/base/data/home/apps/***/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/***/;/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/php55_dynamic/fc2f1b4915ea2bca/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/***/webhook.php on line 8
```

Line 8:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Core\\": "Classes/",
            "Telegram\\": "Classes/Telegram",
            "PushEvent\\": "Classes/PushEvent"
        }
    }
}
```

So now i delete vendor from .gcloudignore - and app is work on GAE, but this thing make me sad :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly tell GAE to run the `composer install` or `composer dump-autoload`.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "gcp-build": [
            "composer install"
        ]
    }
}
```

Tip1: GAE caches the install files, and sometimes you may want to not use it: `gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache]`

Tip2: I recommend you to change the document root of the application in app.yaml to not expose the vendor dir to the outside world.

```
runtime_config:
  document_root: public
```

Directory structure:

```
src
 - OtherFolder //PSR-4
    - ClassA.php 
public
 - index.php
vendor
 - autoload.php
 - ...
compose.json
app.yaml
```

The require will have to reference the parent folder

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

And the composer.json only needs one psr4 entry

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I create file package.json with your script, but still have error with requre :(

Comment: Really ?  @Maksim Can you put your code at github and share it with me ?

Comment: I found! In php55 runtime composer dont work - only for php72.

Comment: shouldn't document_root be public, not src ?